# Simple XML is not displaying my url tag data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I managed to clean my xml but when I display the data all tags show but the tag with a URL`TempImageURL` does not display the url when I echo.

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lists>
    <Property>
        <Reference>123123</Reference>
        <Images>
             <TempImageURL>https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&amp;userId=7414</TempImageURL>
        </Images>
    </Property>
</lists>
```

My php

```
$xml_source='simple_prop2.xml';


$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_source);

foreach ($xml->Property as $prop){
    echo $prop->Reference.' '.$prop->Images->TempImageURL.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: I have tested it with your content and I display the TempImageURL property as in the file. Have you done the test with just this bit of the XML file?

Comment: I have added int he Reference tag. The reference tag works.

Comment: Well, it works from a string : http://codepad.viper-7.com/x4BqMh

Comment: your code is working perfectly with php 5.5, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/NgyS6z

Comment: oops, Shikiryu already posted the same working code on the same cpdepad, LOL

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml_source='simple_prop2.xml';
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_source);

foreach($xml->Property as $prop){
    echo $prop->Reference.'<br>';
    foreach($xml->Property->Images as $chk)
   {
    echo $chk->TempImageURL.'<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: can you give some explanation ? Or put your new information in question ?

Answer (score 0):

Error in your code "failed to open stream"
Add path with file name.

for example

```
$xml_source='http://localhost/test/simple_prop2.xml';
```

Comment: I have added in the path and it didn't display the URL tag. As I said it does show the other tags but not the `TempImageURL`.

Comment: Other than I didn't found any issue, it's working file. URL "https://x.ctrl.com/Image.ashx?Id=e1f47a89-c289-43e1-a2c2-0d35196a97ee&userId=7414" displaying in output. Try the same in other system or on other browser/browser version.